# Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::NotAcceptable: [406] {"error":"Content-Type header [] is not supported","status":406}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I'm trying to get a project running, but anything that uses elastic search crashes with this error:

```
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::NotAcceptable: [406] {"error":"Content-Type header [] is not supported","status":406}
/Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/elasticsearch-transport-2.0.0/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:201:in `__raise_transport_error'
/Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/elasticsearch-transport-2.0.0/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:312:in `perform_request'
/Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/elasticsearch-transport-2.0.0/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:20:in `perform_request'
/Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/elasticsearch-transport-2.0.0/lib/elasticsearch/transport/client.rb:128:in `perform_request'
/Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/elasticsearch-api-2.0.0/lib/elasticsearch/api/namespace/common.rb:21:in `perform_request'
/Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/elasticsearch-api-2.0.0/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/indices/create.rb:84:in `create'
/Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/searchkick-1.4.0/lib/searchkick/index.rb:13:in `create'
/Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/searchkick-1.4.0/lib/searchkick/index.rb:147:in `create_index'
/Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/searchkick-1.4.0/lib/searchkick/index.rb:198:in `reindex_scope'
/Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/searchkick-1.4.0/lib/searchkick/model.rb:53:in `searchkick_reindex'
/Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/searchkick-1.4.0/lib/searchkick/tasks.rb:26:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/searchkick-1.4.0/lib/searchkick/tasks.rb:24:in `each'
/Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/searchkick-1.4.0/lib/searchkick/tasks.rb:24:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/bugsnag-6.2.0/lib/bugsnag/integrations/rake.rb:16:in `execute_with_bugsnag'
/Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I've got no idea what's going on. I've installed via `brew install elasticsearch@2.4` and run by `brew services start elasticsearch@2.4`

Any ideas?

Comment: Due to versioning differences this can happen.

Answer (score 1):

I got there in the end. For others with this issue:

You may need a specific version of elasticsearch (I needed 2.4):

- `brew uninstall elasticsearch`
- `brew install elasticsearch@2.4`
- `pkill -f elasticsearch` # OSX specific
- `brew services start elasticsearch@2.4` # you might need to wait a few mins
- `curl 'http://localhost:9200/?pretty'` # this tests if elasticsearch is up and running

Comment: I was facing same issue , i fixed it, after installing java and reinstall elastic search.